# No default engine facing error by express.js

Tags: mean

Hi I am trying to build a MEAN stack chat application with socket.io and i am facing this error i have done ng-build even but this eventually not able to solve my error

I am attacking code of my files please can some one help that what exactly is the problem.

my app.js looks like this :-

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const favicon = require('serve-favicon');
const logger = require('morgan');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var chat = require("./routes/chat");
var app = express();
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'false'}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

app.use('/chat', chat);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mean-chat')
.then(()=>console.log('connection successful'))
.catch((err)=>console.log(err));

module.exports = app;
```

where as my chat.js looks like this

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose  = require('mongoose');
var app = express();
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var server = require('http').createServer(app);

server.listen(4000);

// socket io
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('User connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
      console.log('User disconnected');
    });
    socket.on('save-message', function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      io.emit('new-message', { message: data });
    });
  });

  /* GET ALL CHATS */
  router.get('/:room', function(req, res, next) {
    Chat.find({ room: req.params.room }, function (err, chats) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      res.json(chats);
    });
  });

  /* SAVE CHAT */
  router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    Chat.create(req.body, function (err, post) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      res.json(post);
    });
  });

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('Express REST API');
});

module.exports = router;
```

when i try to hit url localhost:3000 it shows my UI which is absolutely correct

and when i try to hit my url localhost:3000/chat it shows

express chat api which is correct.

but when i try to hit the URL localhost:3000/book or localhost:3000/chat/book i am facing error like this

Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.
    at new View (D:\edWiseChatApp\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:61:11)
    at Function.render (D:\edWiseChatApp\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:570:12)
    at ServerResponse.render (D:\edWiseChatApp\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1008:7)
    at D:\edWiseChatApp\app.js:33:7
    at Layer.handle_error (D:\edWiseChatApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:71:5)
    at trim_prefix (D:\edWiseChatApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:315:13)
    at D:\edWiseChatApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (D:\edWiseChatApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (D:\edWiseChatApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Layer.handle_error (D:\edWiseChatApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:67:12)
    at trim_prefix (D:\edWiseChatApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:315:13)
    at D:\edWiseChatApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (D:\edWiseChatApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (D:\edWiseChatApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Layer.handle_error (D:\edWiseChatApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:67:12)
    at trim_prefix (D:\edWiseChatApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:315:13)

please can some one help in solving this i want to give this assessment to an interviewer

Answer (score 0):

In your error handler, you are rendering a view onError.
You have to set a view engine to render your views.

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
```

Also, you have the set your views directory.

```
app.set('views', './viewsDirectory')
```

Comment: what will be my viewsDirectory can you answer last question please

Comment: It looks like you used `express-generator`. If so, it should be `'./views'`

Comment: I do not have anything name as views in my app I have used the angular cli app generator and followed tutorial "https://www.djamware.com/post/58e0d15280aca75cdc948e4e/building-chat-application-using-mean-stack-angular-4-and-socketio"

Comment: :( No help its just loading only. with terminal msg of Get / --ms--

Comment: Change `res.render('error')` to `res.send('there was an error')`

Comment: just imagine what it did "on localhost:3000" it started showing there was an error